# How to assess for balance of propensity score matching covariates in Stata?

Tags: stata, propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect

I am comparing outcomes of a treated cohort (n=127) to a control cohort (n=732) using teffects propensity score matching in Stata. I did initial comparisons of baseline characteristics between the two cohorts using parametric, nonparametric and chi square statistics. Those characteristics that were significant were used as covariates for the matching process. The matching was using:

```
teffects psmatch
```

[image: ATE]

My understanding of this is that propensity score matching in Stata is done with replacement. How do I go about assess that each covariate is well matched using similar methods above, given that each patient may be matched to more than 1 patient? Or can psmatch be done without replacement in Stata?

I've tried using:

```
tebalance sum
tebalance box
tebalance density
```

[image: tebalance sum]

[image: tebalance density]

However, these are not typically reported in manuscripts or have p values assessing for differences between the matched cohorts.